Здравствуйте Мне при запуске трансляции через обс выдаёт ошибку
Ошибка называется Description is invalid. На сайте который предлагает обс описания ошибки нету, в интернете в видеороликах про эту ошибку не рассказывают.
вот мой канал : www.youtube.com/@MihaGd-g2o
я пытался найти видео об этой ошибке в ютубе, спрашивал у знакомых. Думал все эти действия мне помогут, но ничего не получилось
